# Android web application on cloud storage

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, web-applications, cordova

I have a cloud storage website and I want to create an Android application for that website.

I tried 2  methods.

First Method

Using Phonegap to open a remote website which handles everything and its built-in PHP so everything works fine. But a Cloud Storage app must allow uploading and downloading. In Phonegap I can upload through the website but can't download directly to local storage. It can only be done locally if my website is in the local www folder. Also in this way API of Phonegap can't be used either. If I download any file the browser opens up, in this case.

Second Method:

I tried to use Phonegap locally and just create an API of my cloud storage website so that locally with the help of jQuery ,Ajax so that I can post data to the remote URL, but that can't be done due to the Same Origin policy. I may receive the JSON data of files and show but can't log the user in and other features. :( Again a problem.

What else can I do? Is there any other method or solution you can provide me regarding these two methods or any alternative method I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the kinds of data you're talking about there are several alternatives.

You're describing a cloud storage app (I'm assuming like drop box or Google drive right).

Therefore you'll want to write to the file system instead of some kind of database (locally ofc)

I would therefore check out the following api docs;
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

Examples are there too.

PS ive had same origin problems in development, but they seem to go away in production, try testing there too.

Comment: Means how to log them into website, by overcoming the same origin policy problem and other features happening due to this, too. During your development did you faced the same origin policy, How can it go away in production do tell me please

Comment: In development I was testing the HTML files by opening them from my file system. By production, I just mean testing on a handset. If you're still having problems, then look into serving JSONP instead of normal json, that also worked for me.

Comment: Means should i use json in all type, Also one thing same origin policy dont block cookies.I have tried that cookies are sent by remote php.Should i use cookies to check users are logged in and show them their files. is this thing safe.

Comment: if you use a cookie that only stores an access token, and that token expires in a reasonably amount of time, you should be ok.